# Orthogonal matrix ("if" or "if only")

Tags: linear-algebra

It is given that $$A^{-1}=A^T$$ if $A$ is orthogonal. Is this statement an "if" or "only if" statement? More specifically, can we show that a matrix is orthogonal by showing the above equality or can there be instances where this is coincidentally true and not orthogonal?

Answer (score 4):

Both directions are true.

**If** direction: suppose that $A$ is orthogonal. An orthogonal matrix satisfies $A^T A = A A^T = I$. Therefore, $A^T$ is $A$'s own inverse.

**Only if** direction: suppose that $A^T = A^{-1}$. Then $A A^T = A A^{-1} = I$ and similarly $A^T A = A^{-1} A = I$. Therefore, $A$ is orthogonal.